# jmeter read credentials from CSV.worng credentials still script is successful.Does it check database while running?

Tags: csv, jmeter

http://www.markschabacker.com/blog/2013/05/10/jmeter_with_webforms_authentication/

http://ivetetecedor.com/how-to-use-a-csv-file-with-jmeter/

I have followed above links to take credentials from CSV file. I have observed with wrng credentials in CSV file, script PASS. Does this script actually checks database ? I have not experienced though. I have given wrong credentials in CSV but, jmeter script run did not failed for login step.

Answer (score 1):

JMeter treats `2XX` and `3XX` HTTP response codes as successful. Even if you enter wrong credentials server's response may be `200` so sampler will be considered successful.

The solution to conditionally fail a test is using i.e. [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) which will be looking for `Welcome, ${USERNAME}` text in the response and mark the test as failed if the line is not found.

See [How to Use JMeter Assertions in 3 Easy Steps](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) guide for comprehensive information on all the JMeter Assertions.

Comment: congrats on reaching 10K :)